# Is it unethical to network into a job with a vendor contact?

Tags: hiring-process, professionalism, ethics

My current employer has brought in a couple of firms to pitch us their product offerings in an informal fashion: "We're thinking about doing x with y, can you show us how you might help us with this?"  We're not actively negotiating a sale or a service agreement.

I would like to reach out to the folks I've met from these firms and try and network my way into a job with them.

Is this sleazy and/or unethical?  I realize it may be if they were poaching me, but this is the other way around: I'm looking to jump ship.

Comment: No one here can tell you what's unethical and what isn't. Your ethics are your own and we don't know the ethical expectations of your current employer. If you're looking for the blessing of strangers on the internet, you have mine. Go for it.

Comment: Can we assume that there is no non-compete clause that would stop you from switching to them?

Answer (score 5):

> Is this sleazy and/or unethical?

I don't think it is unethical for you at all.  You have found some people you would like to potentially work with, and you are contacting them.  Whether you met them at work or through a job ad seems somewhat irrelevant from your standpoint (as an individual employee).  If this were a client of your firm, that might be a bit different and could be violating your contract, but as you describe it the situation doesn't seem to be an ethical question for you.

I think the ethics question will probably be more difficult for the vendor if they choose to speak with you, even if you are the one approaching them.  Your firm may get a bad taste about you leaving for this vendor, even if both you and the vendor are clear about your pursuit of the job.  But that is not for you to worry about.

The fact that you mention that you are looking to jump ship certainly helps your argument.  You are looking to leave regardless, and this vendor is one option.  The company may be less inclined to hold a grudge against the vendor if it is clear that you are unhappy and seeking new opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

It's only unethical if you give them preferential treatment.  But...  Managing your reputation is a lto about avoiding even the appearance of impropriety.  So you have to be beyond reproach in your dealing with them.  Also depending on your situation, you may want to be up front with your boss about your search.  Disclosure helps alleviate some of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend some caution here. Are you fully aware of the level of the relationship between your current employer and the people they've brought in? I ask this because flogging your skills to them could backfire, i.e. they could possibly rat you out to your current employer. Doesn't even have to be intentional on their part. It simply could slip out in an *informal* setting like the one where they came to pitch to you. If you've the luxury of time, try to build your own personal, informal relationship with these guys and then pitch. Or look elsewhere